# Changing data retention settings on existing data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, timezone

Is it possible to change the data retention settings of an already-created DE?  I have DE's that are automated.  An automation puts data view information into these DE's but when I edit, I cant see the option to modify the retention settings.

Also when it comes to time format for event dates in the data views (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_open.htm&type=5)

Is it for MC to store it as an EPOCH time instead of a specific time zone?"

Answer (score 7):

You can change data retention settings for existing data extensions, even when they contain data. This can for sure be done in Contact Builder:
[image]
Just click on Edit under Data Retention, and change the setting to On:
[image]
If Data Retention is already set, using same approach should also allow you to change the settings.

With regards to timezone, all the event timestamps in SFMC (e.g. open and click timestamps) are stored in system time, which is UTC-6.

Comment: OOOOOO Thanks the data retention settings are not viewable in email studio, but in contact builder.  Very helpful.

With the timestamp it is NOT possible to change from utc-6? just wondering - so our developers would have to do a conversion function

Comment: You're welcome @Bloodborne - remember to mark the answer as accepted/upvote if it has been helpful. You can't change the default system time, unfortunately.

Comment: Hi Lukas, can I ask when the data retention applies the changes? I have reconfigured data retention policy for a DE (through contact builder) which haven't had it before. I set up: delete individual records after 1 day. I have waited for over 12 hours and it still doesn't delete the previous records yet